# Scheduling task based on device plug in (USB)

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, event-log

I am looking for a trigger (service or log) that is generated automatically once a device (old or new) is plugged into the PC - the goal is to start a script that notices this event and starts the script automatically.

due to limited resources ,  I cant install watchdog or any services like this.
therefore , I am looking for windows based solution.